# Memory issue with query of huge table from Oracle database with ADO in Excel VBA

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, ado, adodb

I need to use VBA to query a big data table (2.000.000 rows and 130 columns) from Oracle database and save it into text file.

The code I am using is the following

```
Dim DBConnection As ADODB.connection
Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet

'prepare string for connection
Dim strConnection As String
strConnection = "DRIVER=Oracle in OraClient11g_Home32;SERVER=" & database & " ;UID=" & username & ";PWD=" & password & ";DBQ=" & database & ";"

Set DBConnection = New ADODB.connection

'open connection
With DBConnection
    .CommandTimeout = False
    .ConnectionString = strConnection
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With


Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
RecordSet.Open strSQLQuery, DBConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

Do While RecordSet.EOF = False

    str = ""
    For x = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
        If IsNumeric(RecordSet.Fields(x).Value) Then
            dx = RecordSet.Fields(x).Value
            str = str & Format(dx, "0.############") & delimiter
        Else
            str = str & RecordSet.Fields(x).Value & delimiter
        End If
    Next x
    Print #FH, str

    RecordSet.MoveNext

Loop
```

The problem is that probably ADO tries to store in the recordset all the queried data, which will be several GB of data, thus using too much RAM.

I need to find a way to limit the number of rows that are stored in RAM at one time, so that I can download and save as many row as I want without having any issue with the RAM.

I researched but I cannot find anything about this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676691(v=vs.85).aspx) property on the `ADODB.RecordSet` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should try setting `CursorLocation` to `adUseServer`...